# How to create cache in opcua asycio file

Tags: python, python-asyncio, opc-ua

I want to create cache file for opcua server using opcua-asyncio, I have looked at opcua-asyncio github repository , but I did not understand enough, it was mentioned that cache can be created but nobody mentioned how can be cache created. so I am wondering how can I create cache file for optimize the performance of my python file. here is the code I am using  :

```
import asyncio

import logging import sys from asyncua.common.ua_utils import value_to_datavalue

sys.path.insert(0, "..")

from asyncua import Server

async def main(): logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO) server = Server()

await server.init()


server.set_endpoint("opc.tcp://localho:4140")

await server.import_xml("Opc.Ua.Di.Nodeset2.xml")
await server.import_xml("Opc.Ua.Machinery.Nodeset2.xml")
await server.import_xml("Opc.Ua.Pumps.Nodeset2.xml")
await server.import_xml("custom.Nodeset.xml")


#starting!
async with server:
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

if name == "main":

asyncio.run(main())
```

Could someone please provide a solution?
What is the easiest way to create a cache file?

**FYI I want to run this file into raspberry pi!**

I tried several ways but unfortunately, neither of them worked.

your advice and solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the feature was removed because of safety concerns or just got lost in the port to asyncio.
So currently this feature doesn't exist.

Comment: Then how would you optimize the performance of python-asyncio file in raspberry pi ?
because for me it took almost 4 minutes to run all these above mentioned nodeset file in raspberry pi.

Comment: You could try to pickle the Server Object, before starting it.

Comment: I did not understand exactly, could you please provide me an example for better understanding?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html